# Determining the number of vertices with a certain degree

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $A$ and $B$ be the partite sets of a bipartite graph with $22$ vertices. Given that $A$ has $12$ vertices, every vertex in $A$ has degree $3$, and every vertex in $B$ has degree $2$ or $4$, determine how many vertices have degree $4$.

---

I tried this:

Set $n_2$, $n_3$, $n_4$  to the # of vertices with degree $2, 3, 4$. Then $n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 22$ and $2n_2 + 3n_3 + n_4 = 2|E|$.

But I am not sure how to proceed. I guess I need to use the fact that $G$ is bipartite. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have $n_3 = 12$ because $A$ has $12$ vertices and all vertices of degree $3$ are just vertices of $A$.

Your first equation now look like $n_2 + n_4 = 10$.

But since it's a bipartite graph, every edge has one "endpoint" in $A$ and another "endpoint" in $B$. By counting the "endpoints", one gets another equation: $3\times 12 = 2n_2 + 4n_4$.

This then gives $n_2 = 2$ and $n_4 = 8$.

Comment: Sort of confused about how you got $3 \times 12 = 2n_2 + 4n_4$?

Comment: Every edge has one endpoint in $A$ and another endpoint in $B$, hence the total number of "endpoints" (i.e. the sum of degrees of vertices) in $A$ and in $B$ must be the same.